# Unable to chroot mount point?

Tags: debian, centos, chroot, bind-mount

```
# cd /mnt
# file $(which chroot)
/usr/bin/chroot: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64-ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1922fc941e62b1cd0954c5fbf22bc37f7ef84870, stripped
# which chroot
/usr/bin/chroot
```

```
# ls /mnt/bin/bash
/mnt/bin/bash
# chroot /mnt mnt/bin/bash
-bash: /usr/bin/chroot: No such file or directory

# cp -a /usr /mnt
# chroot /mnt mnt/bin/bash
- bash: /usr/bin/chroot: No such file or directory
```

I have been trying to rescue a centos 7 from the rescue mode (debian distro, the hosting company has it that way). I tried every possible solution on the internet and unable to `chroot` to `/mnt` the above messages

PS: I bind mounted, proc, dev and sys

Latestet update:

```
root@rescue:/# ls /bin/bash
/bin/bash
root@rescue:/# whereis bin/bash
bash: /bin/bash /etc/bash.bashrc /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
root@rescue:/# ls mnt/bin/bash
mnt/bin/bash
root@rescue:/# chroot /mnt  mnt/bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘mnt/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
root@rescue:/# usr/sbin/chroot /mnt  mnt/bin/bash
usr/sbin/chroot: failed to run command ‘mnt/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
root@rescue:/# ^C
root@rescue:/# ls /mnt/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ls: cannot access /mnt/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
root@rescue:/# chroot /mnt /usr/bin/bash?
chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash?’: No such file or directory
root@rescue:/# chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
root@rescue:/# ldd /bin/bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcccbd8000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f519ec9e000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f519ea74000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f519e870000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f519e4c5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f519eec3000)
root@rescue:/#
```

Comment: doing ls /mnt/bin/bash show that there is bash, also here the output for both commands sugested. Posted it as an image for readbility. Many thanks in advance

Comment: root@rescue:/mnt# /usr/sbin/chroot /mnt  /mnt/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/chroot: failed to run command ‘/mnt/bin/bash’: No such file or directory  also running like this still get an error

Comment: Eyyy Artem I just post a picture with the commanda you recommended, please need any help, I past again. file $(which chroot)
/usr/sbin/chroot: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1922fc941e62b1cd0954c5fbf22bc37f7ef84870, stripped
root@rescue:/mnt# which chroot
/usr/sbin/chroot

Comment: What about `chroot /mnt` ? ;-) There's no need to specify the path to `bash`

Comment: Like @ArtemS.Tashkinov suggested `chroot /mnt` should work.  If you want to give the name of the binary to run, that name is relative to the new root of the chroot, so it'd be `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`

Comment: chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
 No luck with that also, I am beyond desesperated, has been 10 days now....

Comment: And with `chroot /mnt /usr/bin/bash`?

Comment: The `/bin/bash` inside your chroot is dynamically linked (as per your `file` output).  Are the files on which it has runtime dependencies also contained within your chroot directory (e.g., do you have `/mnt/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`)?  You could also try using a statically linked version of `bash`.

Comment: Also, please don't post pictures of text -- just copy/paste the text.

Comment: Until you ran the `cp` it should have been simply `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`. Now it's anyone's guess whether that'll still work. Unlikely though because you've copied Debian's `/usr` on top of your CentOS `/usr`. Do you have a backup?

Comment: @AndyDalton bash also needs the `libnss_*.so` libraries, which are loaded on demand and not shown by `ldd /bin/bash`.

Comment: Just updated the questions with more details, I just fail to see where Iam going wrong! :( I do have a backup of all centos files and folders in another server wich is like a mirror to this one, i tried everything suggested here and still no luck.

Comment: To @AndyDalton I did not have /mnt/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 inside this directory I copied from root and trying to chroot the message i get is the following: root@rescue:/mnt/lib64# chroot /mnt
/bin/bash: relocation error: /lib64/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference

Comment: I see you tried `chroot /mnt /usr/bin/bash?`, with a question mark at the end. That question mark should not be there.  Also, it would be fairly easy to find the `bash` executable in the chroot with `find /mnt -type f -name bash`. Then use the pathname that this reports, but without the initial `/mnt`, in the `chroot` call.

Comment: @Kusalananda that was a typo but without it the message is the same, the thing is I have another centos and there is no problem on doing chroot there, let me try the command you suggested

Comment: Instead of writing here, if anyone want to do a teams or skype paid live sesion feel free to hit me @neusacaxicane

Comment: @Kusalananda here it root@rescue:/mnt# find /mnt -type f -name bash
/mnt/jailed/bin/bash
/mnt/usr/bin/bash
/mnt/usr/bin/jessie-armhf/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bash
/mnt/usr/bin/jessie-armhf/usr/share/menu/bash
/mnt/usr/bin/jessie-armhf/bin/bash
/mnt/rootfs/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bash
/mnt/rootfs/usr/share/menu/bash
/mnt/rootfs/share/lintian/overrides/bash
/mnt/rootfs/share/menu/bash
/mnt/var/usr/bin/bash
/mnt/var/www/vhosts/natopart.com/usr/bin/bash
/mnt/var/www/vhosts/chroot/usr/bin/bash
root@rescue:/mnt# chroot /mnt /var/usr/bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/

Comment: /mnt/rootfs/share/menu/bash
/mnt/var/usr/bin/bash
/mnt/var/www/vhosts/natopart.com/usr/bin/bash
/mnt/var/www/vhosts/chroot/usr/bin/bash
root@rescue:/mnt# chroot /mnt /var/usr/bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/var/usr/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
root@rescue:/mnt# chroot /mnt /usr/bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
root@rescue:/mnt# chroot /mnt /usr/bin/jessie-armhf/usr/share/menu/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/jessie-armhf/usr/share/menu/bash’: Permission denied
root@rescue:/mnt#